# How to maintain tab state in android

Tags: android

I've two tabs with two different contents.

- Tab1->video streaming
- Tab2->listview.

While click an `listview` item, I'll go to details page `activity`. When back is pressed, it will move back to `listview` well. But in background, the video (Tab1 content) is playing. How to stop this?

My code:

...

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // sets the Bundle
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // sets the context
        setContentView(R.layout.videostream);
        myVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.vview);
        mProgress = new ProgressDialog(this);


        PlayVideo();

    }

    private void PlayVideo() {
        try {

            mProgress = ProgressDialog.show(VideoActivity.this, "",
                    "Buffering video...", true);
            mProgress.setCancelable(true);


            myVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(vSource));
            myVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
            myVideoView.requestFocus();
            myVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    mProgress.dismiss();
                    myVideoView.start();
                }
            });

         } catch (Exception e) {

            mProgress.dismiss();
            System.out.println("Video Play Error :" + e.toString());
            finish();

        }

    }

    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {

        mStartTime = myVideoView.getCurrentPosition();
        outState.putInt("restartTime", mStartTime);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        myInt = savedInstanceState.getInt("restartTime");
        myVideoView.seekTo(myInt);

        myVideoView.start();

    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {

        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

       // 2 means landscape and 1 means portait mode
       if (newConfig.orientation == 2) {
           mProgress.dismiss();

       }

    }
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        myVideoView.stopPlayback();

    }
    @Override
      public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();

            PlayVideo();
        }
```

Comment: stop the video in onPause, and restart onResume...

Comment: ive done like this only.But still it continues..

Comment: please post your onPause et onResume methods from Tab1 so we can understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Pause the video in the list's onItemClickListener and resume it in onResume()

Answer (score 0):

Sanjay you can do one thing you have two tab.One contains the vedio and another contains the listview when you move from one tab to another then your first activity go to onPause and when you will coming back then first activity will be onresume.So,i think you have to srtat vedio in onResume() and stop it in onPause().

If it work then please let me know.